Fees for a mufti
Here are many questions for personal advice, and the most common answer is "ask a mufti".
Well, muftis cannot feed and make a living out of "thank-yous".
Question is: what is the appropriate payment for a mufti?

Muftis are usually sustained by scholarships (from the state or from their institute) and gifts\donations from the public. There isn't any payment or fee for getting a fatwa itself, indeed many scholars hold that taking payment for it from the questioner is not permissible. If you manage to end up with a Mufti who requires a fee then he will tell you what he thinks is appropriate -  this is not something which has a fixed answer.
